# require user to select Checkbox

Tags: php, checkbox

So basically, I want to require the user to select from checkbox ...

Here is addpost.php:

```
<form action='' method='post'>
    <p><label>Title</label><br />
    <input class= "form-control" type='text' name='postTitle' value='<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['postTitle'];}?>'></p>
    <p><label>Description</label><br />
    <textarea name='postDesc' cols='60' rows='10'><?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['postDesc'];}?></textarea></p>
    <p><label>Content</label><br />
    <textarea name='postCont' cols='60' rows='10'><?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['postCont'];}?></textarea></p>
    <!--For textarea's rather then making the admins enter the html for the text themselves its better to use an editor-->
     <script>
            CKEDITOR.replace( 'postDesc',{customConfig:'/sics/ckeditor/ckeditor_config.js'});
            CKEDITOR.replace( 'postCont',{customConfig:'/sics/ckeditor/ckeditor_config.js'} );
     </script>
    <fieldset>
        <label><h5>Select a category</h5></label><br>
        <?php   
        $stmt2 = $db->query('SELECT catID, catTitle FROM category ORDER BY catTitle');
        $checked = '';
        while($row2 = $stmt2->fetch()){
            if(isset($_POST['catID'])){
                if(in_array($row2['catID'], $_POST['catID'])){
                   $checked="checked='checked'";
                }
            }
            echo "<input type='checkbox' name='catID[]' value='".$row2['catID']."' $checked> ".$row2['catTitle']."<br />";
        }
        ?>
    </fieldset>
    <br>
    <p><input class="btn btn-primary btn" type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'></p>
    <?php include('../includes/submitpost.php');?>
    </form>
```

Here is when user submits

```
<?php
//if form has been submitted process it
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    //collect form data
    extract($_POST);
    //very basic validation
    if($postTitle ==''){
        $error[] = 'Please enter the title.';
    }
    if($postDesc ==''){
        $error[] = 'Please enter the description.';
    }
    if($postCont ==''){
        $error[] = 'Please enter the content.';
    }
    if(!isset($error)){
        try {
            $postURL = slug($postTitle);
            //insert into database
            $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO posts (postTitle,postURL,postDesc,postCont,postDate) VALUES (:postTitle, :postURL, :postDesc, :postCont, :postDate)') ;
            $stmt->execute(array(
                ':postTitle' => $postTitle,
                ':postURL' => $postURL,
                ':postDesc' => $postDesc,
                ':postCont' => $postCont,
                ':postDate' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
            ));
            $postID = $db->lastInsertId();
            //add categories
            if(is_array($catID)){
                foreach($_POST['catID'] as $catID){
                    $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO post_cats (postID,catID)VALUES(:postID,:catID)');
                    $stmt->execute(array(
                        ':postID' => $postID,
                        ':catID' => $catID
                    ));
                }
            }
            //redirect to MainPanel page
            header('Location: ../users/MainPanel.php');
            exit;
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
//check for any errors
if(isset($error)){
    foreach($error as $error){
        echo '<p class="error">'.$error.'</p>';
    }
}?>
```

Is it possible? cause I cant get it to work

Comment: Do you want to do the check on the client side/ or the server side? I'm sorry, for a trivial task, you may want to cut down your code and focus on the problem area rather than supply us with your entire code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have multiple checkboxes with same name (array), you can't use required attribute for "at least one checkbox" (http://jsfiddle.net/frantisekmasa/kvtbqLe7/2/).

You should check it server-side:

```
if(isset($_POST['catID']) && ! empty($_POST['catID']) {
    // User has selected at least one checkbox
} else {
   // User hasn't selected checkbox
}
```

Comment: I don't think that makes sense. Only checked boxes get sent to the server so PHP can't check if it's empty.

Comment: @itsols When no checkboxes are sent, the first condition would be false.

Comment: On servers most Linux/Apache servers, if you try to see whether a field is empty without it being set, you get an error. If you're a mere Windows user working on a development machine, you're very unlikely to see this error.

Comment: @itsols When first condition is false, the second one isn't processed btw.

Comment: I'm afraid you're wrong about the last comment. I don't think that evaluation stops when the condition is false. It MUST complete the evaluation as far as I know. If what you're saying is correct, simply rewriting the conditions in a different order will change code behaviour and I don't think that's how it happens. Do you have a reference to show that you're correct? I'm just curious.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
<input type= "checkbox" name="field" required="required" />
```

Comment: Apparently this doesn't work on Safari. But it doesn't matter since I don't usually use it.

Comment: Not going to downvote you as that is a correct response, but use this one with caution as it's only [supported](http://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/09-required.html) in the newer browsers (I'm looking at you IE)

Comment: @Duniyadnd I don't think the 'older IEs' matter since after XP stopped its updates nobody would dare use XP with IE6 or older :)

Comment: Also, you should consider the JQuery validation plugin (http://jqueryvalidation.org/).

Comment: If I had a choice of staying away from Safari or the older browsers, I'd also stay away from JQUERY and whatever other framework. I prefer a 'lighter' site than a more fancy 'all-compatible' one. But I guess it comes down to the goal of the application/site.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

`<input type='checkbox' name='catID[]' value='".$row2['catID']."' $checked required>`

**JSFiddle demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/5f7663b0/

Answer (score 0):

try this

add the java script in between headers

```
                     <script type="text/javascript"> 
                     function checkForm(form) { ... if(!form.catID[].checked) { alert("your customised message here"); form.catID[].focus(); return false; } return true; }
                      </script>

                      edit the form part as
                      <form action='' method='post' onsubmit="return checkForm(this);">

                        <input type="checkbox" name="catID[]"  id="catID[]" value=".$row2['catID']." />
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add the word "required" to the input field

Comment: Please? Why you rate me down? I just answered something someone else did 3 minutes after me?

Comment: Honestly, I did not rate you down... I only gave a comment. If I rated you down, I would have given a good reason. That's a sickness with some of the users who just down-rate and walk away. You probably got down-rated because your answer was not complete. I'm not sure why the actual down-rating was done.

Comment: @mbo - I rated you down by mistake, and when I realized what I did, I tried to change it but it had already been six minutes. Sorry about that. I think the initial reason was because your response was not enough of an explanation - if you think about the individual and the type of question he was asking, it's quite basic, and could have easily been googled, ideally a little bit more of hand holding could have been helpful.